Wrong Redirect Angular Router (to localhost)
This is the example url :
localhost:4202/pages/users/STSP0001PNIENOUIJX/dashboards/level/0

app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pages/users',
    loadChildren: () => import('./@modules/users-dashboard/users-dashboard.module').then(mod => mod.UsersDashboardModule),
  },
  ...
]

UsersDashboardRoutingModule
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':userId/dashboards',
    loadChildren: () => import('../monitoring-levels/monitoring-levels.module').then( (module) => module.MonitoringLevelsModule)
  },
  { path: '', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

MonitoringLevelsRoutingModule
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'level/:levelId', component: MonitoringDashboardComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: `level/${DEFAULT_LEVEL_ID}`},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: `level/${DEFAULT_LEVEL_ID}`}
];

MonitoringDashboardComponent
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="monitoringLevelID">
  <level0-monitoring-dashboard *ngSwitchDefault></level0-monitoring-dashboard>
  <level1-monitoring-dashboard *ngSwitchCase="1"></level1-monitoring-dashboard>
  <level2-monitoring-dashboard *ngSwitchCase="2"></level2-monitoring-dashboard>
</ng-container>

With the example url(or with other example), I get a redirect to localhost:4202.
Other example :

localhost:4202/pages/users/STSP0001PNIENOUIJX/dashboards/level/1
localhost:4202/pages/users/STSP0001PNIENOUIJX/dashboards/

This works only with this modified :

remove path: "" of MonitoringLevelsRoutingModule
add pathMatch: 'full' to MonitoringLevelsRoutingModule

MonitoringLevelsRoutingModule
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'level/:levelId', component: MonitoringDashboardComponent },
 
  { path: '**', redirectTo: `level/${DEFAULT_LEVEL_ID}`}
];

or
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'level/:levelId', component: MonitoringDashboardComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: `level/${DEFAULT_LEVEL_ID}`, pathMatch: 'full'}
  { path: '**', redirectTo: `level/${DEFAULT_LEVEL_ID}`}
];


do you have a redirect call inside your MonitoringDashboardComponent?

No, I just upload a config file
